# set up javafx scene with multiple nodes

Tags: javafx-2, nodes, scene

I am trying to set up my javafx scene, but i have failed miserable.
basically what i am trying to do is as per attached photo.

[image]

I have tried to set up a gridpane and then position another gridpane withing it so that I can set up the boxes and labels however this is not working properly.

I do not want to use FXML.

can you guys recommend how to go about this set up.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaFx SceneBuilder is a good tool to create Layouts like the one you want to have. Take a look at the official [website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/tools/index.html). The tool creates a FXML file which you can load in your applications `start()` method using:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("application.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Another resource where you can get familiar with SceneBuilder is the #Java and #OracleLearning channels on [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rHcnsEoSK_c).

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of it, but i want to create this in code. my issue is that the gridpane does not span the whole scne even if i set setmaxheight..or setminheight...

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me in setting up the given arrangement:

```
GridPane outerPane = new GridPane();
GridPane innerPane1 = new GridPane();
GridPane innerPane2 = new GridPane();
HBox l = new HBox(new Label("Label"));
l.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
outerPane.add(l, 1, 1);
innerPane1.add(new Circle(20, Color.LIGHTCORAL), 1, 1);
outerPane.add(innerPane1, 2, 1);
innerPane2.add(new Button("Button"), 1, 1);
innerPane2.add(new Label("  Label"), 2, 1);
innerPane2.add(new Button("Button"), 1, 2);
innerPane2.add(new Label("  Label"), 2, 2);
innerPane2.add(new Button("Button"), 1, 3);
innerPane2.add(new Label("  Label"), 2, 3);
GridPane.setMargin(innerPane2, new Insets(5,5,5,5));
outerPane.add(innerPane2, 1, 2);
outerPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
```

[image: Output]

Drop any further confusions in the comments :)